# Jquery: get value to check max - min on change from append inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, append, onchange

I'm currently starting using jquery to create a system where you can add more inputs to insert in a database.

All my system works, I can add more inputs with append function like this:

```
$(add_button).click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){
            x++;
            $(wrapper).append('<div class="tier' + x + '" id="tier'+x+'"><table><tbody> <tr><th class="center">Tier ' + x + '</th><th class="thBorder center"> Range </th><td class="tdBorder td20"><input type="number" class="center min'+x+'" name="min[]" id="min'+x+'" value="0"><label for="min"> Min </label></td><td class="tdBorder td20"><input type="number" class="center max'+x+'" id="max'+x+'" name="max[]"><label for="max"> Max </label></td><th class="thBorder center">   Percentage   </th><td class="tdBorder_right centered"><input type="number" class="center Percentage'+x+'" name="Percentage[]" id="Percentage'+x+'"><label for="Percentage"> % </label></td></tr></tbody></table></div>'); //add input box
        }
        else
        {
            alert('You reached the tier limits')
        }
    });
```

On my backend I receive the array with the information, and I can add to my database, but I wants to check the inputs in real time like this:

Tiers:
Inputs: Min - Max - Percentage.

In the first tier the Min value is by default 0, they can choose any Max value, but in the next tier, the min value needs to be the max value of the last (Maybe check if they write other value they receive an alert "The min value is different than the max value of the last tier, needs to be the same", idk).

Example:
Tier 1: Min - 0 | Max - 20 | Percentage: 5%
Tier 2: Min - 20 | Max - 40 | Percentage: 7%
Tier 3: Min - 40 | Max - 70 | Percentage: 9%

The only solution that I have iss check the values after they writhe with a check button:

```
$("button#check").click(function(){
        $( "div.tiers input" ).each(function( index ) {

            console.log($( this ).val() );
        });
    });
```

And this are my div with the tiers:

```
<div class="tiers">
                        <div>
                            <table>
                                <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <th class=" center"> Tier 1 </th>
                                    <th class="thBorder center"> Range </th>
                                    <td class="tdBorder td20">
                                        <input type="number" class="center min" name="min[]" id="min" max="0" min="0" value="0">
                                        <label for="min"> Min </label>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="tdBorder td20">
                                        <input type="number" class="center" name="max[]" id="max"  min="0" value="0">
                                        <label for="max"> Max </label>
                                    </td>
                                    <th class="thBorder center">   Percentage   </th>
                                    <td class="tdBorder_right centered">
                                        <input type="number" class="center" name="Percentage[]" id="Percentage" max="" min="" step="0.01" placeholder="%" value="0">
                                        <label for="Percentage"> % </label>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Can any help me, please?

Thanks in advance, Greetings.

Comment: @MaximillianoFonseca Why even let the user input anything for `min` on any row other than the 1st? When they tab off a row or focus on a new row, auto-populate the `min` box with the previous row's `max` value. You can use events like `onfocus` or `onblur`

Comment: @RyanWilson That is a good solution, thanks you. But currently the system permits to add the tiers as you want (pushing the button, with a limit number) so If I use the max value I need to restring to add the next tier only If the user write the max value of the previous tier, and how can I access to the last max value? maybe add other tier if the user active the "on focus" function? but how can I get the input value?.
Thanks bro!

Comment: @MaximillianoFonseca You can make the `min` box `readonly` on tiers other than `tier 1`. You can get the previous rows `max` value using an iteration of the inputs for `max` with Jquery `.each()` -> `$('.center.max).each(function(index, element){});`

Comment: @RyanWilson
I have it:
`$( "input.center.max" ).each(function( index ) {
                console.log($( this ).val() );
            });`, how can I iter like "row.size() - 1" to get the last max value?
Thanks you!

Comment: `$("button#check").click(function(){
            var total = $( "input.center.max" ).length;
            $( "input.center.max" ).each(function( index ) {
                if(index == total -1) {
                    console.log($( this ).val() );
                }
            });
        });`
I found, ill try to implement the solution, ty @RyanWilson!

Comment: You're welcome. Glad I could help.